# Python: How to statically refer to the return type of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, annotations

If I imported a function from a module, can I make the linter & type checker to refer to its return type?

- I don't want to call the function
- I don't want runtime solution, like `inpsect` module.
- For some reason, I can't import the type itself, e.g. its not meant to be imported.

```
def func(a: T1, b:T2) -> T3: ...
```

```
from module import func

x: func.return_type = 22  # ideal solution ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! `typing` offers this out of the box

Some additional information is available here at [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) python docs reference

```
import typing
def f(a: int) -> str:
    return str(a)
print(typing.get_type_hints(f)['return'])
```

Running that yields:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a runtime solution, just like `inspect`. I want `b = typing.get_type_hints(f)['return']` and get the linter to understand that `b` will be a `str` without running the code.

Comment: I think it might be beneficial if you described what you are actually trying to do. This might be an XY problem.